# Automatic copy of new Kernel to `/boot/efi` upon kernel update

Tags: debian, systemd

How can I detect a kernel upgrade with systemd to start a copy of the new kernel and `initrd.img` to `/boot/efi/EFI` partition in Debian Jessie?

I'm trying to use EFIStub, and NOT rely on grub, and later setup secureboot.

I basically followed this article: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFISTUB#Using_systemd
But I don't know what to write in the `PathChanged=` section, which file should I monitor for changes? Because my debian jessie doesn't seem to create `initramfs-linux-fallback.img` files (at least not when I installed an additional, newer kernel from backports.) and the newly generated initramfs files contain version numbers.

Edit: the systemd file mentioned: `/etc/systemd/system/efistub-update.path`

```
[Unit]
Description=Copy EFISTUB Kernel to EFI System Partition

[Path]
PathChanged=/boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
WantedBy=system-update.target
```

Comment: as far as I understand, putting a bash script in `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/` would be a solution, but not using systemd.
I'm trying to create a guide how to setup secureboot on a "modern" UEFI intel 6th gen computer using "modern" software. But to be honest, I didn't completly grasp systemd.

Comment: note: `/etc/kernel/postinst.d` seems to be executed by `dkms`, so maybe it it the way "how to do it properly"